# Oracle 11g to SQL Server 2008 Query Conversion

Tags: sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I'm not a SQL guy, but I've had to convert over some sql from Oracle to SQL Server for a client, I didn't write the initial query or system, so I have very limited understanding on this old code, and I'm having trouble getting the same results. I cannot share sensitive data, but I was hoping someone may see the flaw in my query. Thanks so much.

The original oracle query uses the "(+)" notation in the "WHERE" clause for a left join on project number, and a right join on transaction date and workphase. The right join is the part I'm having trouble with, as it seems to run with no end in SQL Server, as the ORACLE views were materialized. Indexes have had no luck. My only hope is someone can see the problem here!

The Oracle Query:

```
SELECT pr.project_number,
   proj.project_name,
   proj.program_category,
   proj.program_subcategory,
   proj.const_total_amount,
   proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
   proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
   proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
   proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
   proj.const_start_date,
   proj.const_finish_date,
   to_char(trans.transaction_date,'mm-yyyy') as monthyear,
   sum(trans.transaction_amt)
FROM projectVW proj, transactionVW trans
WHERE proj.project_number = trans.project_number (+) AND
    proj.const_finish_date >= add_months(current_date,-36) AND
    proj.const_start_date IS NOT NULL AND
    trans.workphase (+) = 'CONST' AND
    trans.transaction_date (+) <= last_day(add_months(current_date,-1))
GROUP BY pr.project_number,
     proj.project_name,
     proj.program_category,
     proj.program_subcategory,
     proj.const_total_amount,
     proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
     proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
     proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
     proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
     proj.const_start_date,
     proj.const_finish_date,
     to_char(trans.transaction_date,'mm-yyyy')
ORDER BY proj.project_number,monthyear desc"
```

First Attempt:
I attempted to implement the right joins on workphase and transaction date, but this query would run for over 1.5 hours, and eventually timed out, so I removed the right join, thinking that it didn't seem necessary, but this query only gets ~4800 of the 5635 entries the oracle retrieves.

The right join that was taken out was written as:

```
FROM projectVW AS proj LEFT OUTER JOIN transactionVW AS trans ON proj.project_number = trans.project_number RIGHT OUTER JOIN transactionVW AS trans2 ON trans2.workphase = 'CONST' AND trans2.transaction_date <= @EOMo1
```

Query without right join:

```
DECLARE @EOMo1 datetime
DECLARE @FinDate1 datetime
SET @EOMo1 = DATEADD (DAY, -1, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SET @FinDate1 = DATEADD(MONTH,-36,GETDATE())

SELECT proj.project_number,
       proj.project_name,
       proj.program_category,
       proj.program_subcategory,
       proj.const_total_amount,
       proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
       proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
       proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
       proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
       proj.const_start_date,
       proj.const_finish_date,
       CONVERT(CHAR(3), trans.transaction_date, 101) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),    trans.transaction_date, 11) AS monthyear,
      SUM(trans.transaction_amt)
FROM projectVW AS proj LEFT OUTER JOIN transactionVW AS trans ON proj.project_number = trans.project_number
WHERE proj.const_finish_date >= @FinDate1 AND
     proj.const_start_date IS NOT NULL AND
     trans.workphase = 'CONST' AND
     trans.transaction_date <= @EOMo1
GROUP BY proj.project_number,
         proj.project_name,
         proj.program_category,
         proj.program_subcategory,
         proj.const_total_amount,
         proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
         proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
         proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
         proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
         proj.const_start_date,
         proj.const_finish_date,
         CONVERT(CHAR(3), trans.transaction_date, 101) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),        trans.transaction_date, 11)
ORDER BY proj.project_number,monthyear desc
```

This seems to miss any monthyear's that are Null, but those account for 832 rows, and there's only a 622 row gap between the original and the results.

Second attempt: So I tried to go from scratch and try nesting sub queries. This blew up the returned rows to 5500

```
DECLARE @EOMo1 datetime
DECLARE @FinDate1 datetime
SET @EOMo1 = DATEADD (DAY, -1, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SET @FinDate1 = DATEADD(MONTH,-36,GETDATE())

   SELECT proj.project_number,
       proj.project_name,
       proj.program_category,
       proj.program_subcategory,
       proj.const_total_amount,
       proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
       proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
       proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
       proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
       proj.const_start_date,
       proj.const_finish_date,
       CONVERT(CHAR(7),trans.transaction_date,120) AS monthyear,
       SUM(trans.transaction_amt)

FROM 
   (
      SELECT project_number,
             project_name,
             program_category,
             program_subcategory,
             const_total_amount,
             const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
             const_ac_reimburse_pct,
             const_reimbursement_pct,
             const_planned_conversion_date,
             const_start_date,
             const_finish_date

      FROM projectVW

      WHERE const_start_date Is Not Null AND
            const_finish_date >= @FinDate1
   ) AS proj LEFT JOIN 
   (
      SELECT project_number,
             transaction_date,
             transaction_amt

      FROM transactionVW

      WHERE transaction_date <= @EOMo1 AND
            workphase = 'CONST'
   ) AS trans
   ON proj.project_number = trans.project_number

GROUP BY proj.project_number,
         proj.project_name,
         proj.program_category,
         proj.program_subcategory,
         proj.const_total_amount,
         proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
         proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
        proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
         proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
         proj.const_start_date,
         proj.const_finish_date,
       CONVERT(CHAR(7),trans.transaction_date,120)

    ORDER BY proj.project_number,
             monthyear DESC
```

Past these attempts, I'm having a lot of trouble, can someone save me anymore frustration? I can't edit the DB or see execution paths, and the transaction table has no good primary key, other than being matched to project number.

EDIT:
Okay, so with the test mentioned below, the problem seems to be that for a given project, there are entries in the transaction table, but the workphase is not CONST, but it does have a workphase that isn't null. So these entries are discarded and not added to give us a transsum nor a monthyear for the transaction. The project still shows up in the oracle results, but will be null for those entries. So it seems like it's not returning the project table's columns for these.

The ones I checked that are showing up have NULL for transaction amt and monthyear

For example (scrubbed, once again, columns in select order):
(There would be multiple of this first code box's data, with different transaction values)

```
Project-2002,   A description of the project,   2015-04-15 00:00:00.000,    2017-01-11 00:00:00.000,    2012-06-01 00:00:00.000,    500.20, PR
```

Oracle still returns:

```
Project-2002,   A description of the project,   Some_CATAGORY,  Some_SUBCATAGORY    19999999.20,    0,  80,     7/1/2016 0:00,  4/15/2015 0:00, 1/11/2017 0:00  , null, null
```

FINAL EDIT: Fixed it! I switched back to the query that used subquerys, I previously wrote above, and added the "OR NULL" checks to that and it came out fine. I think the problem with the query we were working on was that the WHERE was taking place after the left join, so all the projects were already associated with a workphase, so the whole project was getting taken out when the WHERE checks came through and found a non CONST/NULL workphase. That's only a guess, though.
Much thanks for your help!

Comment: Oracle is returning records that have workphase value other than "CONST"? Maybe I misunderstood how (+) operates, try commenting out the line "AND (trans.workphase = 'CONST' OR trans.workphase IS NULL)" and see if that gives results that match Oracle's.

Comment: No, that was with the workphase line commented out. It should be returning the project that matches project-2002, despite the transaction entries being PR. It should just not add that transaction data to the result

Comment: Hooray! I've seen something like that on another Stack Overflow question once, it's a real nightmare to track down if you can't look at the query plans, and just plain tough even if you can (well, I've never had it happen personally, but it looks tough). Anyway, so glad it works :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @EOMo1 datetime
DECLARE @FinDate1 datetime
SET @EOMo1 = DATEADD (DAY, -1, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
SET @FinDate1 = DATEADD(MONTH,-36,GETDATE())

SELECT proj.project_number,
       proj.project_name,
       proj.program_category,
       proj.program_subcategory,
       proj.const_total_amount,
       proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
       proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
       proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
       proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
       proj.const_start_date,
       proj.const_finish_date,
       CONVERT(CHAR(3), trans.transaction_date, 101) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),    trans.transaction_date, 11) AS monthyear,
      SUM(trans.transaction_amt)
FROM projectVW AS proj LEFT OUTER JOIN transactionVW AS trans 
        ON proj.project_number = trans.project_number
WHERE proj.const_finish_date >= @FinDate1 
    AND proj.const_start_date IS NOT NULL 
    AND (trans.workphase = 'CONST' OR trans.workphase IS NULL)
    AND (trans.transaction_date <= @EOMo1 OR trans.transaction_date IS NULL)
GROUP BY proj.project_number,
         proj.project_name,
         proj.program_category,
         proj.program_subcategory,
         proj.const_total_amount,
         proj.const_non_ac_reimburse_pct,
         proj.const_ac_reimburse_pct,
         proj.const_reimbursement_pct,
         proj.const_planned_conversion_date,
         proj.const_start_date,
         proj.const_finish_date,
         CONVERT(CHAR(3), trans.transaction_date, 101) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),  trans.transaction_date, 11)
ORDER BY proj.project_number,monthyear desc
```

I don't have access to Oracle now, and even when I did it wasn't my main focus, but I think the (+) notation best corresponds to "Or is NULL", rather than specifically an outer join. It can be used to implement outer joins, but that was only part of its function. I've rewritten your query with this in mind.

It may still have performance issues, but let's see if we can get a correct result set before we address them.

EDIT:
OK, now that you've identified a few specific projects that fall through, let's get the relevant details on them. We are really only concerned with fields that participate in the decision to include, or that are needed to identify the record. So run the following queries replacing my ProjectNumbers with a few of the ones that are not included plus a few of the ones that are correctly included, and edit your original question to include the query and the output. Run them on both Oracle and SQL so we can compare.

```
SELECT proj.project_number, proj.project_name
       , proj.const_start_date, proj.const_finish_date
FROM projectVW AS proj 
WHERE project_number IN ('PROJECT-5001','PROJECT-5002')


SELECT trans.project_number, trans.workphase
       , trans.transaction_date, trans.transaction_amt
FROM transactionVW AS trans 
WHERE project_number IN ('PROJECT-5001','PROJECT-5002')
```

Maybe we'll see something relevant, like workphase is a blank instead of a NULL, or it has a trailing space. If you are in any way unsure about extra characters, you can replace "trans.workphase" with "'#' + trans.workphase + '#' as workphase" in the select statement.

EDIT 2 (2014-09-04 12:08 PM EST):
OK, lets have a look at what is excluding them. Pick 3 projects that are not included but should be, and 2 that are correctly included, and put them in the IN list in the query below. Run the query. Hopefully you will see all 5 projects. Next, start un-commenting the AND rows in the WHERE clause and re-run each time. When rows disappear between runs, that's the condition that's failing. Post it back, along with the data and we'll focus our efforts there.

```
SELECT proj.project_number,
       proj.project_name,
       proj.const_start_date,
       proj.const_finish_date,
       CONVERT(CHAR(3), trans.transaction_date, 101) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), trans.transaction_date, 11) AS monthyear,
       SUM(trans.transaction_amt) as TranSum
FROM projectVW AS proj LEFT OUTER JOIN transactionVW AS trans 
        ON proj.project_number = trans.project_number
WHERE 
    proj.project_number IN ('PROJECT-5001','PROJECT-5002','PROJECT-5003','PROJECT-5004','PROJECT-5005')
    --AND proj.const_finish_date >= @FinDate1 
    --AND proj.const_start_date IS NOT NULL 
    --AND (trans.workphase = 'CONST' OR trans.workphase IS NULL)
    --AND (trans.transaction_date <= @EOMo1 OR trans.transaction_date IS NULL)
GROUP BY proj.project_number,
         proj.project_name,
         proj.const_start_date,
         proj.const_finish_date,
         CONVERT(CHAR(3), trans.transaction_date, 101) + CONVERT(CHAR(4),  trans.transaction_date, 11)
ORDER BY proj.project_number,monthyear desc
```

Comment: Closer! This one is pulling 5524 entries. The oracle pulls 5635. I made some corrections to the numbers of rows I'm pulling, as some of those numbers were from august. The "second attempt" with the nested queries is actually pulling 5663, so it's also fairly close. I'm not too worried about performance, their DB is quite the bottleneck right now, and this is a overnight query.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @user2107943, can you see anything in common for the rows picked up by one but not the other? A good test might be to send the output to a text file for each and use a DIFF tool to see what records are different?

Comment: Still working on that. File comparer doesn't keep it in mind if a row in missing in one file, so it then thinks matching rows after that aren't on the same line number are differences, which makes it a little slower to find them.
I did figure out my EOMo1 Calculation was calculating the last day of this month instead of last month, though.

Comment: Here's a data scrubbed entry your query didn't get but the oracle did, doesn't seem to tell me anything, even compared to entries that were included.The finish date is after 2011-09-03 15:13:36.607, the Transaction Date is before 2014-08-31 00:00:00.000; start date is not null. Other entries were grabbed that have null monthyear and null transaction amounts, so those are fine too

Still searching though.

Columns are in order of the SELECT query's


"PROJECT-5001","A Description","SOMECATAGORY","SOMESUBCATAGORY",57231.675,90,"",10,"","2015-10-21 00:00:00","2017-06-09 00:00:00","",""

Comment: @user2107943, see if you can get your output to omit line numbers so the DIFF tool can re-sync after a mismatch. Or pass it through a filter to strip out the line numbers, but they'll make it very hard to troubleshoot this. I'll have a look at this, but it may take me a bit. Looks like useful info, though, and good catch on date mismatch!

Comment: Okay, I wrote a script to compare the files myself and pull a CSV of only the missing rows. The main thing I'm seeing in this file is that transaction_date (monthyear) is null, transaction_amt is null, and so is workphase (modified the query to select workphase also) for every row except one. I'm not seeing anything wrong with start or finish dates, they all fit within the bounds defined.